# what is the best way to display banner in android app?

Tags: android, admob

i'm looking for a solution to be able to display, manage and control a banner in my app being able to change the banner in future. I've already tried ad mob and its house ad feature. but it seems that it also displays random ads provided by google.

Comment: What's your question? Of course AdMob displays random ads from Google...that's how it works. What do you want to do differently?

Comment: You can read more about Admob keywords and ad filter. https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3150235?hl=en

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: I want my own banner to be displayed only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to display something so specific, AdMob seems inappropriate. I suggest just creating your own layout to display exactly what you want. You can even create a custom `View` which can easily be reused wherever you wish.

Comment: thank you. so what if i want to change what the banner displays or disable the banner after i've published my app?

Comment: @mdehghani You can deliver the content via HTTP, if you wish. Then your banner is just a simple `WebView`. Assuming that the `WebView` loads a static URL, you can update the content at that URL to anything you wish. Anything more dynamic will take quite a bit more work.